# Is there a way to achieve component specific localization support in a Blazor application

Tags: localization, calendar, components, blazor, hijri

I was thinking about creating a Blazor app in which showing more than one culture specific calendar is one of its use and so I need to achieve component specific localization in that app.

I had gone through Microsoft documentation for configuring localization support in my app,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

I also had additional help by surfing and came through this link by using resources file for configuring the culture specific values,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/localization-in-blazor-server/

This is an example config of my resources files (containing culture data) for the calendar component,

[image]

[image]

My requirement would be something like follows,

[image]

Its a crude example bear with me, but what I want is something like this, but by using resources file and guidelines by Microsoft and other sites I referred doesn't seem to fulfil my requirement.

Is there a way to achieve this in any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Localization of strings? Try providing some sample code for what you would like to do.

Comment: I have updated some details for your reference in my question.

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.